# turn off NHib Validator logging when Debugging

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-validator

When I have log4net set to DEBUG in a project with an NHibValidator dependency, I *lots* of feedback from NHibValidator. When the Validator is not the focus of the debug run however, this is just noise.

Does anyone know how to filter this out?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to employ regular log4net configuration to specify the logging level for the logger name that the validator uses. See http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#loggers.

Comment: The nuisance is that there are quite a few loggers, enough that I had hoped there might be a configuration convenience provided by the validator. But yeah I guess I can just clutter up my own config and filter them out. Cheers

Comment: Actually you are right, just filtering on "NHibernate.Validator" keeps it quiet. Cheers